# Android open keyboard change layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to make layout that contains three `EditTexts` and two `Buttons`. But when I create layout and open soft keyboard some views are hidden. And I also used `ScrollView.

My Code is below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/code_selector"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/code_selector"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/password"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/code_selector"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/email">


            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/btnFacebookLogin"
                style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textOr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/btnFacebookLogin"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Or"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textOr"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#AA008000"
                android:text="Next"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Please help me to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: if you are using `ToolBar` you cant't give title like this

Comment: but i want to set title center

Comment: have you any another method?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that some views are bing hidden by the keyboard the view should still be scrollable due to you `ScrollView`. If it is not, consider using either `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` for the enclosing activity in the manifest